# JS, code is executed few times because of (barbajs) Pjax

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have js code that is used to show google map on some pages, when i wanted to start using barbajs(pjax) everything was fine till i checked that my code is executed many times depending of how many times i visited given page for example:

when i visit `http://example.com/regions` barba is fething my page that contains html and js code and execute it, second when i visit `http://example.com/regions2` and there is similar code and in console i got info that my js code is executed twice, when i again visit `http://example.com/regions` code is execuded 3 times and so on. I think the reason for it is that my js code is in browser memory, if it is how i check for it presence? Or how to make that code is execuded once?

My js code looks like this in a nutshell:

```
Barba.Dispatcher.on('transitionCompleted', function() {
    var mapDistributors = mapDistributors || {

        makeMap: function() {
            var loc = this.location.split(','),
                pos = new google.maps.LatLng(loc[0], loc[1]);
            var countryCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(59.9882184, 18.2516778);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 6,
                center: countryCenter,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            this.mapObj = new google.maps.Map(document.querySelector('.mapGoogleDistributors'), mapOptions);

            this.destination = pos;
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: pos,
                icon: 'icon.svg',
                info: {
                }

            })
            this.markers.push(marker);
        },

        handleRoute: function(result, status) {
            if (status != google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK || !result.routes[0]) {
                alert('wrong data entered!');
                return false;
            }
            this.pathRender.setDirections(result);
            this.formInput.value = result.routes[0].legs[0].start_address;

        },

        prepareRoute: function(coords) {
            var renderOptions = {
                mapDistributors: this.mapObj,
                polylineOptions: {
                    strokeColor: '#ff0000',
                    strokeWeight: 4,
                    strokeOpacity: 0.8
                },
                suppressMarkers: true
            }
            this.pathRender.setOptions(renderOptions);

            var pathData = {
                origin: coords ? coords : this.formInput.value,
                destination: this.destination,
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
            }
            this.path.route(pathData, this.handleRoute.bind(this))
        },

        getGeoData: function() {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                function(position) {
                    this.prepareRoute(position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude);
                }.bind(this),
                function(errorObj) {

                    alert('error!');
                }, {
                    enableHighAccuracy: true
                }
            );
        },

        checkGeoSupport: function() {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                var findPositionButton = document.querySelector('#findButton');
                findPositionButton.classList.remove('hidden');
                findPositionButton.onclick = function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    this.getGeoData();
                }.bind(this);
            }
        },

        init: function(options) {
            if (!options.location) return;
            Barba.Dispatcher.on('transitionCompleted', this.makeMap.bind(this));
            Barba.Dispatcher.on('transitionCompleted', this.markersLocation.bind(this));
            // try { google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", this.makeMap.bind(this)); } catch(e) {return; };
            // try { google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", this.markersLocation.bind(this)); } catch(e) {return; };
            // try { google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", this.showInfo.bind(this)); } catch(e) {return; };
            this.options = options;
            this.location = this.options.location;
            this.form = document.querySelector('.mapForm');

            this.formInput = document.querySelector('.inputMap');
            this.path = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
            this.pathRender = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
            console.log(this, document.querySelector('.mapForm'));
            this.form.onsubmit = function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var address = document.querySelector('#search').value;

                this.getLatLng(address, 6);
            }.bind(this);
            this.checkGeoSupport();

        },

        // markers
        placeMarker: function(distrybutors, instalators) {
            for (var i = 0; i < distrybutors.length; i++) {
                var d = distrybutors[i];
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(d.latLng[0], d.latLng[1]);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    // map: this.mapObj,
                    position: latlng,
                    icon: '/bundles/galmetmap/images/galmet_sygnet.svg',
                    info: {
                        name: d.name,
                        address: d.address,
                        phone: d.phone
                    }
                });
                this.addInfo(marker);
                this.markers.push(marker);
            }
            this.mapClustering();
        },

        markers: [],

        htmlInfo: function(info) {

        },

        //find markers

        findClosest: function(position, markersToReturn) {

            var positionAddress = new google.maps.LatLng(position.lat(), position.lng());
            var closest = [];
            var counter = 0;

            mapDistributors.mapObj.setCenter(positionAddress);
            mapDistributors.mapObj.setZoom(11);

            for (var i = 0; i < mapDistributors.markers.length; i++) {
                var marker = mapDistributors.markers[i];
                var distance = mapDistributors.calcDistance(marker.position, positionAddress);
                if (distance <= 150) {
                    var obj = {
                        distance: distance,
                        info: marker.info
                    }
                    closest.push(obj);
                }

            }

            var chunkClosest = closest.sort(function(a, b) {
                return a.distance - b.distance;
            });
            var results = document.querySelector('.result');
            results.innerHTML = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < markersToReturn; i++) {
                var distance = document.createElement('div');
                distance.innerHTML = 'Odległość w km ' + chunkClosest[i].distance;
                var instalator = mapDistributors.htmlInfo(chunkClosest[i].info);
                instalator.appendChild(distance);
                results.appendChild(instalator);
            }
            window.location.href = "#result";
        },

        calcDistance: function(position1, position2) {
            return (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(position1, position2) / 1000).toFixed(2);
        },

        addInfo: function(marker) {
            marker.addListener('click', function() {

                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: mapDistributors.htmlInfo(marker.info),
                });
                infowindow.open(mapDistributors.mapObj, marker);
            })
        },

        geocoder: new google.maps.Geocoder(),

        getLatLng: function(address, markersToReturn) {

            mapDistributors.geocoder.geocode({
                'address': address
            }, function(results, status) {
                if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    mapDistributors.findClosest(results[0].geometry.location, markersToReturn);
                } else {
                    alert('reason : ' + status);
                }
            })
        },
        mapClustering: function() {
            var mcOptions = {
                imagePath: 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/images/m'
            };
            this.cluster = new MarkerClusterer(this.mapObj, this.markers, mcOptions);
        },

        markersLocation: function() {

            var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
                    var jsonData = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
                    if (jsonData.status) {
                        this.placeMarker(jsonData.distrybutors, jsonData.instalators);
                    } else {
                        console.log('error');
                    }
                }
            }.bind(this)
            xmlHttp.open("GET", document.querySelector('#urlAdress').value, true); // true for asynchronous
            xmlHttp.send();
        },
    }
    mapDistributors.init({
        location: "50.1943227,7.8434933"
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The barba.js event `transitionCompleted` is fired each time a new page is loaded.

For your use you might:
Check the current url/page at each `transitionCompleted`, check if the current page is correct (and eventually add a control in order to not run the code twice).

The best solution would be to use Barba.js Views:
http://barbajs.org/views.html